# How do I represent C++ template classes in LePUS3?

Tags: c++, templates, modeling

Given the code:

```
template <typename Entry>
class BaseClass {
    // ...
};

class ConcreteClass : public BaseClass<ConcreteEntry> {
    // ...
};
```

What does the LePUS3 CodeChart for this look like? Does the templating have to be represented or can it be neglected?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, templating is an implementation detail of the pattern and is not represented in the LePUS3.